# replacing defs with lambda expressions python 3.3

Tags: python, function, lambda

i'm new to programming but im stuck with a question, which im asking myself. I made an example like this:

```
u = 1

def method1(x):
    def method2(n):
        def method3(m):
            return x + n + m
        def method4():
            global u
            u += 1
        method4()
        return method3
    def method5(y):
        return x + y
    return method2, method5
```

The question is: Can I replace some of these defintions with lambda expressions? I dont want to change the semantics of the code above. I was thinking about something like this:

```
u = 1
def method1(x):
    def method2(n):
        lambda m: x + n + m
        def method4():
            global u
            u += 1
        method4()
    lambda y: x + y
    return method2
```

If this what i have done is correct, can i replace even more definitions without changing the semantics of the code or am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not completely correct since you **do not store** the lambda expressions nor do you **return them**. A semantically equivalent program should be:

```
u = 1

def method1(x):
    def method2(n):
        method3 = lambda m: x + n + m
        def method4():
            global u
            u += 1
        method4()
        return method3
    method5 = lambda y: x + y
    return method2, method5
```

> can i replace even more definitions without changing the semantics

I think unless you make the program totally unreadable, this is about it. Mind however that you do not have to transform all functions into lambda expressions: it is simply useful and can sometimes improve readability. But it should not be a goal by itself.

> **Note**: like @juanpa.arrivillaga says it is however not recommended to store lambda expressions into variables, etc. It is against [style guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations). It is not semantically incorrect, but is not considered good coding.

Comment: You are right I forgot to store and return them. ty

Comment: This is actually *against* PEP8. The whole point of `lambdas` is that they are anonymous. If you are storing them, then you should just use `def`. See: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I agree that this is not very wise, but it is an equivalent program. Furthermore if you feed a lambda expression to a function, well it is not "anonymous" to the callee, since he named it with a parameter name :).

Comment: there's also `functools.partial` in the same state of mind.

Comment: Sure, but again, it is probably worth noting in the answer that this goes against the recommendations of the style guide. I up-voted, I just think that this should be clear.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I've added a note mentioning your comment :).

Comment: It is interesting to see how the style guide phrases it "The use of the assignment statement eliminates the sole benefit a lambda expression can offer over an explicit def statement (i.e. that it can be embedded inside a larger expression) " -- if something has only *one* benefit, it should be used sparingly. Other than as `key` parameter for a sort or for attaching a function to a widget in Tkinter, I've almost never found a natural use for them.

Comment: @JohnColeman yes, essentially, in Python, the only real use of a `lambda` is for code brevity when passing functions as arguments. Quick, one-off uses.